# Object cannot be converted to string when using Optional class in Java

Tags: java, option-type

I have the following code trying to use the Optional class:

```
import java.util.Optional;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  public String orelesMethod() {
    return "hello";
  }

  public void test() {
    String value;
    value = Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse(orelesMethod());
    System.out.println(value); 
  }

  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();

    hello.test();
  }
}
```

when compiling it, it says:

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
    value = Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse(orelesMethod());
```

I can not find it out what is the problem, can anyone help on it?

Thank you!

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(null)` results in an `Optional<Object>` which means `orElse` must return an `Object` (which may or may not be a `String`). Use `Optional.<String>ofNullable(null)` to get an `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have defined `value` to be of type `String`, but `Optional.ofNullable(null)` returns `Optional<Object>` because any object type can be `null` and you did not specify the actual type. Then you are calling `orElse` on the object of type `Optional<Object>` and because `T` is `Object`, the `orElse` method returns an object of type `Object` which cannot be converted to `String`.

Therefore you need to specify the type while calling `ofNullable`:

```
value = Optional.<String>ofNullable(null).orElse(orelesMethod());
```

You might also want to use `orElseGet` method in order not to call `orelesMethod` when the optional contains value.

Answer (score 0):

A String is an Object, but an Object is not necessarily a String and thus this error. Try this :

```
public String orelesMethod() {
        return "hello";
    }
    public void test() {
        Object value;
        value = Optional.ofNullable(null).orElse(orelesMethod());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`Optional<T>` is the new (since Java 8) way of handling values which might be `null`.

You get the value by calling `.get()`.

Note that calling `.get()` without the value being set throws an NoSuchElementException.

See the reference: [Class Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

---

Edit:

Also, the return value of your `orElse()` will be of the same time you initialized you class with. Since that's not a String but `null` you don't get a String as return.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: @nix9 You mean the "can anyone help on it?"-question? Yes, that's actually not answered. I replied to the problem, not to the answer.